# Traversing from one node in xml to another using Python

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I am very new to XML with Python and I have the following XML string that I get as a response from a network device:

```
'<Response MajorVersion="1" MinorVersion="0"><Get><Configuration><OSPF MajorVersion="19" MinorVersion="2"><ProcessTable><Process><Naming><ProcessName>1</ProcessName></Naming><DefaultVRF><AreaTable><Area><Naming><AreaID>0</AreaID></Naming><Running>true</Running><NameScopeTable><NameScope><Naming><InterfaceName>Loopback0</InterfaceName></Naming><Running>true</Running><Cost>1000</Cost></NameScope><NameScope><Naming><InterfaceName>Loopback1</InterfaceName></Naming><Running>true</Running><Cost>1</Cost></NameScope><NameScope><Naming><InterfaceName>GigabitEthernet0/0/0/0</InterfaceName></Naming><Running>true</Running><Cost>1</Cost></NameScope></NameScopeTable></Area></AreaTable></DefaultVRF><Start>true</Start></Process></ProcessTable></OSPF></Configuration></Get><ResultSummary ErrorCount="0" /></Response>'
```

I have the following code to retrieve the interface information along with the interface cost associated with it. However I would also like to get the 'AreaID' tag associated with each interface as part of my dictionary. Unable to navigate the tree correctly to retrieve the AreaID tag value:

```
for node in x.iter('NameScope'):
int_name = str(node.find('Naming/InterfaceName').text)
d[int_name] = {}
d[int_name]['cost'] = str(node.find('Cost').text)
```

This code gives the following output when 'd' is printed:

```
{'GigabitEthernet0/0/0/0': {'cost': '1'},
 'Loopback0': {'cost': '1000'},
 'Loopback1': {'cost': '1'}}
```

I want something like this in the output:

```
{'GigabitEthernet0/0/0/0': {'cost': '1', 'area': 0},
 'Loopback0': {'cost': '1000', 'area': 0},
 'Loopback1': {'cost': '1', 'area': 0}}
```

Any suggestions or modifications to my code will be really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the [`preceding`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/preceding) notation:

```
node.xpath(".//preceding::AreaID")[0].text
```

Complete code I am executing:

```
from lxml import etree as ET

x = ET.parse("input.xml")
d = {}
for node in x.iter('NameScope'):
    int_name = str(node.find('Naming/InterfaceName').text)
    d[int_name] = {
        'cost': str(node.find('Cost').text),
        'area': node.xpath(".//preceding::AreaID")[0].text 
    }

print(d)
```

Prints:

```
{
    'Loopback0': {'cost': '1000', 'area': '0'}, 
    'Loopback1': {'cost': '1', 'area': '0'}, 
    'GigabitEthernet0/0/0/0': {'cost': '1', 'area': '0'}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, 'x' is an  xml.etree.ElementTree.Element object. Hence, node doesnt have the xpath attribute. I am on Python 2.7. Also, I tried what you suggested by doing this: "area =  str(node.find(".//preceding::AreaID")[0].text)" and I got this error "SyntaxError: prefix 'preceding' not found in prefix map
"

Comment: Also, my input is not an xml file, but an xml.etree.ElementTree.Element object.

Comment: @pypep278 well, it works for me even if I define a `data` string variable and define `x` as `x = ET.fromstring(data)`. What happens if you use `xpath()` method?

Comment: Thank you so much! I was using the following import as opposed to yours and hence it failed for me: import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET